# Converting your dataframes into dict to iterate: drawbacks and dangers?

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary

Converting a DataFrame to a dictionary before iterating through it about 20 times faster.

Any drawbacks or reasons to avoid this trick?
What do we loose ?
What are the dangers?
Thanks!

```
import time
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100000, 2)), columns=list('AB'))


st = time.time()
x=0
for i, row in df.iterrows():
   x+=(row.A)*(row.B)
print('Result', x, 'via df Iterrows,\t\t Execution time:', time.time() - st, 'seconds')


st = time.time()
x=0
dico=df.to_dict('records')
for i in range(len(dico)):
   row_A, row_B = [dico[i][k] for k in ['A', 'B']]
   x+=(row_A)*(row_B)
print('Result', x, 'via browsing dicto,\t Execution time:', time.time() - stime. Timeds')
```

Comment: `x = (df.A*df.B).sum()` this is even 200x faster than dict.

Comment: Yes, true.
But this syntax becomes more complex when you're implementing more complex functions. Sometimes actual iteration is necessary

Comment: when you will have more comeplex function then ask question with this function - maybe someone will know better solution instead of for-loops. Sometimes better solution can be use modules which uses threading/multiprocesssing in pandas.